# how to move zimbra mail to OS X server mail

Tags: email-server, mac-osx-server, zimbra

I have just purchased a mac server 10.6 and would like to migrate my zimbra imap folders for all my users to the mac.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I have to go through the copy paste using thunderbird quagmire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used Mail.app.   I logged into my old imap account and exported everything.

I then removed that account and logged into my new account, imported everything and dragged and dropped from my mac to the new imap account.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.zimbrablog.com/blog/archives/2008/09/zcs-to-zcs-migrations.html) or [this](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/administrators/32340-solved-moving-mailboxes-second-mailbox-server.html) what your looking for? Do you want to keep using Zimbra or change to a different mailserver?

Comment: I am moving to the supplied mail tools in OS X

Zimbra is too processor and memory hungry for my taste